# Point tracking with scikit-image not working as intended

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-image, image-stabilization

I'm trying to work on **video stabilization** using python and template matching via skimage. The code is supposed to **track** a single **point** during the whole video but the tracking is awfully imprecise and I suspect it's not even working correctly

This is the *track_point* function which **is supposed** to take a video as an input and some coordinates of a point and then **return an array of tracked points** for each frame

```py
from skimage.feature import match_template
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

def track_point(video, x, y, patch_size = 4, search_size = 40):

    length, height, width, _ = video.shape

    frame = rgb2gray(np.squeeze(video[1, :, :, :])) # convert image to grayscale
    x1 = int(max(1, x - patch_size / 2))
    y1 = int(max(1, y - patch_size / 2))
    x2 = int(min(width, x + patch_size / 2 - 1))
    y2 = int(min(height, y + patch_size / 2 - 1))
    template = frame[y1:y2, x1:x2] # cut the reference patch (template) from the first frame
    track_x = [x]
    track_y = [y]
    #plt.imshow(template)
    half = int(search_size/2)
    for i in range(1, length):
        prev_x = int(track_x[i-1])
        prev_y = int(track_y[i-1])
        frame = rgb2gray(np.squeeze(video[i, :, :, :])) # Extract current frame and convert it grayscale
        image = frame[prev_x-half:prev_x+half,prev_y-half:prev_y+half] # Cut-out a region of search_size x search_size from 'frame' with the center in the point's previous position (i-1)
        result = match_template(image, template, pad_input=False, mode='constant', constant_values=0) # Compare the region to template using match_template
        ij = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(result), result.shape) # Select best match (maximum) and determine its position. Update x and y and append new x,y values to track_x,track_y

        x, y = ij[::-1] 
        x += x1
        y += y1
        track_x.append(x)
        track_y.append(y)

    return track_x, track_y
```

And this is the implementation of the function

```py
points = track_point(video, point[0], point[1])
# Draw trajectory on top of the first frame from video
image = np.squeeze(video[1, :, :, :]) 
figure = plt.figure()
plt.gca().imshow(image) 
plt.gca().plot(points[0], points[1])
```

I expect the plot to be somehow regular since the video isn't that shaky but it's not.

[image]

For some reason the graph is plotting almost all of the coordinates of the search template.

**EDIT:** Here's the link for the video: https://upload-video.net/a11073n9Y11-noau

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share your input video?

Comment: Yes, here it is: [video](https://upload-video.net/a11073n9Y11-noau)

Comment: I can't seem to see the video, all I see is a blank "upload-video.net" image throughout the video. Maybe it's best to use a file sharing site like dropbox? I'd need to be able to download the video to play with the code locally.

Comment: Uploaded on gdrive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q5tIdVWkSR4fLFgFHBZGs-v9xINVoRjG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you maybe resolve the problem?